# Nginx Configuration for Dynamic URL Segments as Arguments for Parent Segment Index

Tags: nginx, config, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to set a location in the configuration that allows me to do something like `https://example.com/car/<vin>` which would not go to a `<vin>` application or directory but to `/car/index.html`. From there, I would read the URL or pass `<vin>` to `/car/index.html`.

I have tried various regex location blocks, like the one below, but they all result in a 404 when accessing `/car/<vin>`.

```
location ~ ^/car/(.*)$ {
    root $document_root/car/
    index index.html;
}
```

What would be an appropriate location block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use a regular expression? The prefix location would also work as it matches any URI that **begins with** `/car/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /car/ {
    try_files /car/index.html =404;
}
```

Using `$document_root` in the `root` statement may not work, and the `index` directive only works with URIs that end with a `/`. The `try_files` statement is probably the simplest solution. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: This works for me. I just had to add an if check to make sure it would only work for `/car/<vin>` and not something like `/car/<vin>/wheels`: `if ($request_uri !~ "^/car/[A-Z0-9]+$") { return 404; }`.

Comment: You could use a regular expression `location` instead, but they are evaluated in order, so be aware of potentially conflicting locations elsewhere in the server block. For example: `location ~ ^/car/[A-Z0-9]+$ { try_files /car/index.html =404; }`